# How to test when you use FaceID/ FingerPrint to login in the app on React Native

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am working on the React Native app. Using Expo to run the simulator

My idea is to save credentials on the **AsyncStorage**. And fetch it when the user has already logged in.

If I set a mock ID in advance at useEffect(), it lets me log in to the app.

But when I save user credentials in **asyncStorage** and fetch it later using useEffect, **I don't know how to test it through Expo. On Expo, I could not wait until the session is time out (if there is a way please enlighten me) or I could not hard shut down the app, if I shut down Expo, the next time running it, I could not test it as well**. I am so frustrated when working without knowing how to test it.

I use **expo-local-authentication** for the **FingerPrint** and **FaceID**

**Login function** and how I can store email, password in AsyncStorage

```
//fetch the data
fetch(global.API_DIRECTORY + global.USER_LOGIN, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }),
    })

.then((responseJSON) => {
        //try to save the credentials on AsyncStorage
        try {
          AsyncStorage.setItem("email", responseJSON.email);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("password", responseJSON.password);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("account_type", responseJSON.account_type);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
```

**Authentication function**

When I handle login, If I use the mock credentials, it lets me log in to the app, but the problem is when I get credentials from AsyncStorage. **I don't know how to test it on Expo**

```
handleAuthentication = async () => {
    //retrieve credentials from AsyncStorage
    AsyncStorage.getItem("email").then((email) => setEmail(email));
    AsyncStorage.getItem("password").then((password) => setPassword(password));
    AsyncStorage.getItem("account_type").then((account_type) =>
      setAccount_type(account_type)
    );

    // create mock up ID. The FingerPrint works and let me actually login in the app
    //setEmail("admin@gmail.com");
    //setPassword("admin");
    //setAccount_type("0");

    if (account_type != "") {
      let result = await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync();
      if (result.success) {
        setScanned(true);
        const data = {
          email: email, //login data for your account
          password: password,
        };
        const headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        };
        axios
          .post(global.API_DIRECTORY + global.USER_LOGIN, data, {
            headers: headers,
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            if (result && result.data) {
              const AUTH_USER = result.data.email;
              // _storeUser(AUTH_USER);
              // _storeToken(AUTH_TOKEN);
              if (AUTH_USER) {
                let account_type = "";
                result
                  ? (account_type = result.data.account_type)
                  : invalidLoginAlert();
                switch (account_type) {
                  case "0":
                    global.account = result.data;
                    navigation.navigate("MainMenuScreen");
                    break;
                  case "1":
                    global.account = result.data;
                    navigation.navigate("TechMainMenuScreen");
                    break;
                  default:
                    console.log("account_type incorrect");
                }
              } else {
                Alert.alert("Please login again with your email and password");
                props.navigation.navigate("WelcomeScreen");
              }
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I figure out that Expo can save the credentials even when I shut down the app. So the Finger Print working perfectly now every time useEffect() runs the first time I open the app.